# 2 same Jquery ajax but just one work

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I call two jquery ajax with the same php function but on two different id.

I don't know why but only the first one works. When I switch the order, the other works.

I don't know if I've explain correctly my problem.

Thanks a lot.

```
('#owner_issue, #owner_label_issue').hide();
  $('#owner_group_issue').on('change', function() {
   var owner_group_id =  $(this).val();

   if (owner_group_id!="")
   {


     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/project/owner_by_group2", 
          dataType: "json",
          data: {group_id: owner_group_id},
          success: function(user_list) {
             $('#owner_issue').empty(); // On vide la liste des users
              $('#owner_issue, #owner_label_issue').show();


                $.each(user_list, function(key, v) {
                    //alert(user_list);
                    $.each(user_list[key], function(user_id, name){

                    });

                     $('#owner_issue').append($('<option value="'+user_list[key].user_id+'">'+user_list[key].name+'</option>'));
                });

               // for(var i = 0,i<user_list)
            }
        });
    }
});  



//alert($('#example').children('tr').length);

  $('#owner, #owner_label').hide();
  $('#owner_group').on('change', function() {
   var owner_group_id =  $(this).val();

   if (owner_group_id!="")
   {


     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/project/owner_by_group", 
          dataType: "json",
          data: {group_id: owner_group_id},
          success: function(user_list) {
             $('#owner').empty(); // On vide la liste des users
              $('#owner, #owner_label').show();


                $.each(user_list, function(key, v) {
                    //alert(user_list);
                    $.each(user_list[key], function(user_id, name){

                    });

                     $('#owner').append($('<option value="'+user_list[key].user_id+'">'+user_list[key].name+'</option>'));
                });

               // for(var i = 0,i<user_list)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you stepped through using the debugger console? Also, can you post the code for the two methods called via AJAX (`owner_by_group` and `owner_by_group2`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function owner_by_group()
{
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));        
  $this->load->library('form_validation');

  $this->load->model('project_model');

  $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id');
  $data['user_list'] = $this->project_model->get_owner($group_id);

  log_message('error','USER LISTTTTT json2 = '.print_r($data['user_list'],true));

  echo json_encode($data['user_list']);
}
```

owner_by_group and owner_by_group2 are same. I have tried to duplicate my ajax function just to see if it's works with that little change

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the console debug window?

Comment: No, it's like it doesn't get any trigger on the id "#owner_group"

Comment: If the function is never being triggered on `#owner_group` I would suggest  verifying that the names are correct in the form. Can you post the form code too?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution,

One trigger for each dropdown :

```
$('.owner, .owner_label').hide();
  $('.owner_group').on('change', function() {
   var owner_group_id =  $(this).val();
   alert(1);
   if (owner_group_id!="")
   {

     alert(2);
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/project/owner_by_group", 
          dataType: "json",
          data: {group_id: owner_group_id},
          success: function(user_list) {
             $('.owner').empty(); // On vide la liste des users
              $('.owner, .owner_label').show();


                $.each(user_list, function(key, v) {
                    //alert(user_list);
                    $.each(user_list[key], function(user_id, name){

                    });

                     $('.owner').append($('<option value="'+user_list[key].user_id+'">'+user_list[key].name+'</option>'));
                });

               // for(var i = 0,i<user_list)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't help but notice that your `selector` has also changed from `#owner_group` to `.owner_group` which would also help if you were previously selecting based on an `id` as opposed to the `class`.